# C# Writing hex string from textbox as bytes

Tags: c#, type-conversion, hex

I am trying to convert hex values from a textbox string (ie ffff) to 0xffff as a INT (This way I can use binary writer to write FFFF as 2 bytes in a file).

I actually used this:

```
string hextoconvert = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text).ToString("X8");
```

(But again wasn't sure how to convert the string 0002045E to int 0x0002045E (as 4 bytes)).
If that isn't the right idea then what should I use to convert ***hex values that the user puts in a textbox*** TO ***BYTES?***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: I'm going to bed but I'll be on tomorrow morning to check out the suggestions. I hope I can get my program working! :p

Comment: Depending on usage - you may need to consider if the values need writing "little endian" or "big endian" (i.e. does the 5E get written first or the 00).

Comment: Just use `int.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);` ? But remember to get rid of the forwarding `0x`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14332574/6560478 .. there is so many good duplicate for this one!

Comment: Thank you so much! how can I make the bytes go in big endian though?

Answer (score 0):

```
int.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

This worked, thanks m.rogalski!